# Distribution of the sum of i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be i.i.d random variables with $P(X_1 = m) = 1/10$ for any $ 0 \le m \le 9$. Now I want to calculate the distribution of 
$S := \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{X_n}{10^n}$.

I tried to do this with the characteristic function. So far i got:
$\rho_S(t) = \rho_{\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{X_n}{10^n}}(t) = \prod_{n \ge 1} \rho_{X_n} (\frac{t}{10^n}) = \prod_{n \ge 1} E [ e^{i  t  X_n /10^n}] \prod_{n \ge 1} E [ e^{i  t  X_1 /10^n}] =  \prod_{n \ge 1} (\sum_{j=0}^{9} e^{itj/10^n} * \frac{1}{10})$.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to simplify this expression in order to get another characteristic function of another RV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of its probabilistic meaning. $X_i$ gives a uniformly random digit in base $10$. Hence
$$
\frac{X_1}{10}+\cdots+\frac{X_n}{10^n}
$$
gives the uniform distribution on rational numbers in $[0,1)$ with exactly $n$ decimals.

Now you have an infinite sum. This converges *in distribution* to the uniform on $[0,1)$.